# updating value property for UISlider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Something really basic here I fear. Have three sliders used to control the colour for a colour picker. Moving the sliders updates the values as you would expect but I can't set their *.value* properties.

```
    NSLog(@"A %f %f %f",aRedValue,aGreenValue,aBlueValue);

    redSlide.value=aRedValue;
    greenSlide.value=aGreenValue;
    blueSlide.value=aBlueValue;

    NSLog(@"B %f %f %f",redSlide.value,greenSlide.value,blueSlide.value);
```

gives to the log

```
2011-04-01 21:35:00.894 col1[1264:207] A 0.500000 0.500000 1.000000
2011-04-01 21:35:00.895 col1[1264:207] B 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Why might this be? Setting the UISliders as properties of the hosting view controller or **setNeedsDisplay** does not seem to help. What am I doing here wrong?

Comment: put a `NSLog(@"Red: %@", redSlide);` in your code to check that those sliders are not nil. You will see they are nil, all of them. Either you forgot to connect them or the connection was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think may have found the error in my code. The view loads from NIB after the class so it overwrote any updates that I made with the objects last value. Now have three normal float instance variables and a method that updates the slider value from them when ever required. The key bit was then to call this method after **viewDidLoad** to over write the settings loaded in from NIB.

*Many thanks for everyones help. Had been stuck on it for days but your comments as always helped take the problem apart and solve it.*

Answer (score 1):

Using `[redSlide setValue: aredValue];` is exactly the same as `redSlide.value = aRedValue;` .
I think your `UISlide` is an Interface Builder object and you didn't connect it to your `UIViewController`. Or your 3 color value is all to 0 because if you didn't set `minimumValue` or `maximumValue`, defaults values is respectively to 0 et 1.

So, either you can't access to your `UISlider` objects, either your color values is all to 0 because if there was superior to 0, your `value property` would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Is the minimum or maximum value set to something other than the default?
You might print out the sliders values before you set them, maybe there's something else going on.

[update] I think user288264 is right.

Comment: looked at this but does not seem to be the problem. Liked the idea of printing out values before setting. Were all zero.

Comment: Is the slider instantiated?   Verify with: NSLog(@"slider is 0x%x", slider)

Answer (score -2):

Try:

[redSlide setValue: aredValue];
[blueSlide setValue: value];
[greenlide setValue: value];

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to `redSlide.value = aredValue`.